# Table Views with null as a condition

Tags: sql-server, view

I have two tables, one for music and one for artist. Music has album name, artistID (foreign key), and releasedate. Artist has 3 columns, one for PKID, one for band name, and one for singer name. In the event that it is a band, the band name will be filled out and the singer name will be null. And vice versa.

I can't seem to create a table view that will show the Band name if bandname is not null and vice versa. I've tried many different ways, including one with declaring variables, but nothing ever compiled. Here is the latest thing I've tried. I sort of understand what is going wrong, but I don't what direction to be heading in if I can't declare @BandName.

```
CREATE VIEW MusicWithArtist AS

    IF B.BandName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN 
         SELECT A.Title, A.ReleaseDate, B.BandName
            FROM Music A, Artist B
                WHERE A.ArtistID = B.ArtistID
        END;
    ELSE
        BEGIN
         SELECT A.Title, A.ReleaseDate, B.SingerName
            FROM Music A, Artist B
                WHERE A.ArtistID = B.ArtistID
        END;
```

Comment: I also don't want to use the Join command here

Comment: You are using a join.  You are just deliberately using such an old style that MS may stop supporting it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW MusicWithArtist AS
     SELECT A.Title, A.ReleaseDate, ISNULL(B.BandName,B.SingerName) ArtistName
        FROM Music A, Artist B
            WHERE A.ArtistID = B.ArtistID
```

What environment are you using that would prevent you from using a JOIN??  Ansi-style joins have been specified since SQL92, which is so many years ago it's not funny.

```
CREATE VIEW MusicWithArtist AS
     SELECT A.Title, A.ReleaseDate, ISNULL(B.BandName,B.SingerName) ArtistName
        FROM Music A
        JOIN Artist B ON A.ArtistID = B.ArtistID;
```

Comment: You sir are amazing. You seem to always see my questions and answer them within 30 minutes. As for the Join part, I just wanted to see if it can be done without join :)

Comment: That's cool, I also didn't know you can just omit the AS here. Can AS be omitted completely in all situations?

Comment: For naming of column and table aliases, it can be omitted. For defining views/function/procedures - it is mandatory.